# Gracefully error out template variables in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When there is a line of code in an Angular application that causes an error, the entire template is broken.

For example, this code (which results in an error when we try to assign a value to `foo.bar`):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="home" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Message: {{hello_msg}}</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);
      angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
        controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
          var hello_msg = 'Hello!';
          $scope.hello_msg = hello_msg;

          // malformed JS
          foo.bar = 'app breaks';
        }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Completely breaks the page, and it looks like this:

[image]

Is there some configuration option that I can add to my Angular app so that the page erorrs out more gracefully? Specifically, the variables in the templates that are wrapped in `{{` and `}}`, do not display them at all if there is an error in the app.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: This does not work. the template is still broken even if I include ng-cloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to error out more gracefully would be to use:

```
<div ng-bind-html="hello_msg">
```

The ugly `{{hello_msg}}` would not display when the `foo.bar` breaks the app.

---

Please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9whVMnZDOFLsuOjI170?p=preview) that proves the point

---

IMPORTANT NOTE

To use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) instead of the curly brackets, **you need to include [ng-sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) in your module**.